# How to track when an update will be available via apt

Tags: apt

I am on cosmic and waiting for a bugfix that is part of clang 7.0.1. I know of launchpad.net, which [shows me](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-toolchain-7/1:7.0.1-4) that it is available for disco.

Using a PPA is not a good solution in my case.

How can I track if and when that package might be available for cosmic? Where would this be discussed?

While an answer with a date for this package would be appreciated, I am more interested in a general answer on how to find this out myself.

Comment: That package will never be officially available for cosmic. If a bugfix is released for cosmic, it will be as an update to the `1:7-3` package in cosmic. Is there a bug report against the cosmic version? If yes, please provide a link. If not, file one.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly: Would I open a bug report on launchpad explaining how clang 7.0.0 is broken, that clang 7.0.1 fixes it, and ask for the cosmic package to be updated?

Comment: Yes, but the package will not be updated to 7.0.1; only the smallest possible changes that fix this bug will be applied to the current package (assuming the patch is accepted).

Comment: Got it. Looks like I had a wrong idea of the package management process. Thanks!